# Arabic and JavaMail Issue

Tags: java, email, encoding, outlook, jakarta-mail

i am facing an issue in one of my struts applications. I have JSP page which accepts inputs from the user and sends to a email address. I have set the encoding in the JSP Page as follows.

```
<%@ page  pageEncoding="UTF-8"  contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
```

Now when the user submits the form to action i use the below code to send email to the recipient.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "10.51.10.44");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    properties.setProperty("charset","utf-8");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
    try  {

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            String msg = formatEmail(userForm.getContent(),userForm.getUsername(),ip,host);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject(subject,  "UTF-8");
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain; charset=UTF-8"); 
            System.out.println("subject :-"+subject);
            System.out.println("MESSAGE :-"+msg);
            messageBodyPart.setContent(msg.toString(), "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart( messageBodyPart ); 
            message.setContent( multipart); 
            Transport.send(message);
```

But my recipient is receiving the arabic email's content and subject as junk as follows.

```
Ø³ÙŠØ³ÙŠØ´Ø´Ø³ÙŠØ•ÙƒÙ†Ø´Ø³ÙŠÙƒØªØ³ÙŠØ´Ù…Ø§Ø³ÙŠØ´Ù†Ù„Ø§Ø³ÙŠØ´ØªÙ„Ø´Ø³ÙŠØªÙ„Ø´Ø³ÙŠØ¬Ø´Ø³ÙŠÙ„Ø¬Ø³Ø´ØªÙ†Ø³ÙŠ
```

Please help...I know this is a encoding issue.  I get success if i change the encoding of the jsp to

```
<%@ page  pageEncoding="UTF-8"  contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java"%>
```

But by doing that all the other text which is retried from DB and displayed in JSP pages goes as Question mark.

Comment: Sorry, i don't speak Arabic.  problem is Arabic text is going junk in email. some encoding issue but could not find out where is problem.

Comment: notice the '**:D**' smiley at the end of my comment.

Answer (score 5):

set the content also.

```
msg.setContent(text, "text/plain;Charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: I am using multipart email. i have used this in my code. messageBodyPart.setContent(msg.toString(), "text/html;charset=UTF-8"); now if set it to message i get a exception.

Comment: Rakesh, my guess is that the problem is not with the code which sends email. but the encoding in jsp page which accepts the subject and content of email. If i set the encoding of the jsp charset=iso-8859-1 i am getting the arabic in the email. But this creates issue with the arabic text in page which goes as ????

Comment: ok then set the request and reponse character encoding utf-8 and if you done this then accept answer

Comment: See Rakesh, my issue is far from over. Please read my question once more please. If i am setting encoding to UTF-8 my email goes all junk. If encoding is set to iso-8859-1 i get my email correct buy all the UTF encoded Arabic text in JSP becomes question marks. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the original author no longer cares about this problem, but for future readers, this's how to solve it:

- For a plain text body part:

  ```
  new MimeBodyPart().setText(text, "UTF-8")
  ```
- For setting the subject of the email:

  ```
  msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8")
  ```
- If you're adding an attchement the name of which is in Arabic, you need to set this system property:

  ```
  System.setProperty("mail.mime.charset", "UTF-8")
  ```

  JavaMail uses this property internally to get the default encoding used for the file name of the attachement.

Comment: Ahmed, the issue was 8 years ago,  A lot has changed from API side, and I have solved the issue at that time.